# Missing assembly reference in Release mode in Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

It works fine in debug mode but as I switch to release mode and build, some assembly reference including 'WindowsAzure' , 'HockeyApp' and  'SignaturePad' are missing.

I am new to Xamarin and Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have linking activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your version for compilation and switch to some lower version of Android. This solved my problem.
You can find that under Project > Properties > Application > Compiled using Android version